# Onclick clear or hide label having same class name

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<label class="name">
<input class="required|number error" type="text" name="phone" value="">
<label class="error" for="phone" generated="true">This field is required.</label>
</label>
```

On click clear button I want to clear or hide value of error class label.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".clear").click(function(){
    $(".error").html("");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".clear").click(function(){
    $(".error").hide();
});
```